# are there some tools to make macro codes debuggable like common source code

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb

As we know, during debugging gdb could expand macro when special gcc options enabled.
But it is not convenient enough compared with debugging raw source code.

If there is a tool to expand macro in-place and replace the original source code for gcc to compile, that would be cool

If there is no such a tool, I'm going to create one and here are some rough ideas for your comments

Using "gcc -E" to compile the source code with macros and output the result to some temporary files, make some smart diff/compare between pre-processed file with original source file  to extract the expanded source code and build a final source code whose macros have been expanded

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use gcc -E, then edit the resulting .i file and remove the #line directives around the affected area.  Then compile the .i file.

gcc+gdb could be made to debug macros as if they were inline functions, but I think that would be a fair amount of work in gcc.